# How to create an Single-Portfolio page?

Tags: themes, pages, html

I created a portfolio page to show my works for my theme Everything is ok on my portfolio page, but when I click on an link to go to the portfolio object page, it uses the template's single.php page.

I would like it to use the template page I created "single-portfolio.php".
How do I do this?

Comment: A portfolio page, is that a post in a custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Slug of your Custom Post Type "portfolio" for the filename, as you pointed out, `single-portfolio.php` is correct if your slug is "portfolio".

You just have to take one more step, create the file in the Theme directory (the same folder where your `single.php` is located).

WordPress automatically selects the `single-portfolio.php` for the Portfolio CPT if the file is there, and if it is not there, it takes the `single.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The [WordPress codex page **Template Hierarchy**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) should give you some insight about WordPress theme files naming conventions and how WordPress chooses a certain file and not another:

[image: Graphic Example of the WordPress Template Hierarchy Structure]